Uninstall Managed package with experience site template and theme
I am creating a managed package that includes an experience site template and theme. I installed it in a dev org and I cannot uninstall it.  I have changed the existing site to a different template and theme. I made the site inactive. I have archived the site, as well. It's like there is an old version of the site saved somewhere using the template and theme, like a flow version. Thanks!

I suggest you contact the vendor/package author and if they can't help perhaps raise a support case with Salesforce. I was told, emphatically, on the partner forums (when I asked some questions about it) that trying to package experience sites/templates/themes in a managed package was a bad idea and that it is safer to use an unlocked package for this sort of thing. Perhaps you're hitting one of the many problems this causes...

Thanks Phil! I am making the package so I don’t have anyone to ask. I need it to be managed but I think i can exclude the theme and template.
